# MKH8000 / MZF8000

Tags: microphone, filter, lowend

I've put together a new M/S rig of a MKH8040 + MKH30 - still waiting for some of the pieces to arrive.  I often hear about the strong low end pickup on the 8040 and know that's there's the MZF8000 filter which has a hard low cut at 16Hz (among other features).

I'm curious, to those who have spent some time with the 8000 series mics, especially in a M/S esteem, do you find the MZF8000 to actually be useful to the point it's very much worth dropping the $500 to get it, or more an "hmm, well, it may be useful but not worth the $500" situation.  The MS rig has a stand but is also being prepared as a handheld (Rycote Windshield AE and Connbox 3).  It seems these handheld situations are where mentions of the low frequency pickup are noted.

I am totally willing to drop the cash for the filter, yet wanted to see what the consensus was on how useful the MZF8000 actually is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same kit as yours. Honestly, while the MKH80xx series does have a big low end I've never had an issue with it. I even like it actually -- it's easy enough to filter  it out if I have to, but for many effects that I record it actually adds a lot of oomph.

Now, if you're planning on mounting the 8040 on a boom or doing a lot of handheld work, that's a different story. Handling noise really can become an issue with that mic. But while I've never personally tried the MZF8000 I know that many production sound mixers and boom ops find it quite useless due to its rather high cut-off frequency and gentle slope -- deally you'd want the opposite to suppress handling noise. There are actually quite a few discussions over at jwsoundgroup if you want to read more about it.

EDIT: Personally, the Rycote that I have has been adequate for handheld work. But generally I do try to lock my rig down.

EDIT2: I've also heard good things about the Schoeps LC60 and LC120, respectively.

Comment: The noise I'm referring to is the 16Hz and below - the MZF has a hard-wired low cut at 16Hz, and then it has a selectable rolloff and pad. The question is asking about the 16Hz and below - without the MZF do people find using the 8000 series troublesome in handheld to the point that the filter is a useful investment, or that there's isn't much of a problem.

Comment: I see. I don't think I ever had any real issues with <16Hz. But even if there were any issues, I don't think the MZF8000 would help that much -- I just don't see how 3dB/oct with a cut-off at 16Hz could be effective at all. But again, I've never tied it myself so I could be completely wrong. In any case, I'm curious to hear about your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Stavrosound.

Honestly i don't know if infrasound could be a problem with the 8040. I have heard of the handling noises, but that's mostly higher up right? (40>120 hz). 
I've only had the 8040/mkh30 rig on a stand to compare it with a mkh50/30 combo. I could sent you the resulting wave files (recorded with a sonosax sx-r4)if you're interested.

Regarding the mzf8000 filter option, you could always order that later on right? Or maybe hire a setup with it included?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks!  No worries about sending files.  When the 8040 arrives I'll be able to test the entire set on my 702 and see where we're at.  Since the 30/8040 is my main setup, if the MZF is deemed necessary it would make perfect sense to invest in it.  Yes I can get it after the fact.  I'll just have to test run everything and see what the status is.  My guess is it'll be used more often in a handheld esteem than a stand, but I've got the Manfrotto Nano ready to go when needed.

Comment: ok, let us know what your experiences are. i'm considering buying a 8040 myself and am curious how it works in your setup (rycote etc.). especially regarding handheld work. BTW I love the Nanos they're great!

Comment: so far the setup has worked great.  The Connbox is killer, pretty much decouples the entire M/S array from the suspension.  There was some slight meter-visible low end based on the waveforms (definitely not enough to create any intermod distortion), but nothing audible at all - likely so low in freq it'll rolloff in PT anyway.  So far, withe the Rycote + Connbox = 2 thumbs up (both handheld and stand-mounted).

Comment: Good to hear that! Which rycot did you get? The stereo windshield? Do you have the numbers? There are so many options on the site :)

Comment: Went with the Stereo Windshield AE.  Honestly, I feel the girth on it is 12-15% excessive, but it does a great job.  Wanted to go one length size smaller bit the MKH30 length was the deciding factor.

Comment: 'What is this girth you speak of?' seriously, i don't know what it means... (European over here)

Comment: I refer to the diameter/width